# Python Numpy manipulate matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
[[ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ] 
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 1 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]]
```

and I want to change it in a way, that if there is `1` value in a row, then make two rows above and after to `1` as well, so the output should be:

```
[[ 0 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 ] 
 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 1 0 ]
 [ 0 0 1 0 ]
 [ 0 0 1 0 ]
 [ 0 0 1 0 ]]
```

any idea or help please?

thank you

Comment: Are you able to use SciPy?

Comment: @ajcr yes I can

Comment: The [`binary_dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) function with an appropriate array for the 'structure' kwarg might be a good option in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (x,y) in np.argwhere(n==1):
    xfrom=max(x-2,0)
    xto=min(n.shape[0]-1,x+2)
    for i in range(xfrom, xto+1):
        n[i,y]=1
```

Comment: what is the n? is it the matrix? if so, I get an error of index out of bounds

Comment: You're right. n - matrix, I corrected the upper bound to n.shape[0]-1. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with an array of 0s and 1s, you may want to convert it to an boolean array and make use of the logical operators. And, slicing and indexing in numpy is very handy.

```
def expand_in_place(bool_matrix, expand_up=2, expand_down=2):
    assert expand_up >= 0 and expand_down >= 0

    # expands upward
    for _ in range(expand_up):
        bool_matrix[:-1] |= bool_matrix[1:].copy()

    # expands downward
    for _ in range(expand_down):
        bool_matrix[1:] |= bool_matrix[:-1].copy()
```

---

#### Example usage:

```
matrix = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0]])
bool_matrix = matrix.astype(bool)
expand_in_place(bool_matrix)
print()  # newline
print(bool_matrix.astype(int))
```

Output:

```
In [64]: 
[[0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0]]
```

---

#### Explanation:

1. The key is what happens when you call  `bool_matrix[:-1] |= bool_matrix[1:]` every time.
2. I add `.copy()` because `bool_matrix[1:] |= bool_matrix[:-1]` doesn't work as expected.

   ```
   In [108]: small = np.array([False, False, True, False, False])

   In [109]: small[1:] |= small[:-1]

   In [110]: small
   Out[110]: 
   array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
   ```
3. You can easily extend it to expand in four directions.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier:

```
for row, col in np.argwhere(n == 1):
    n[row-2:row+3,col] = 1
```

Let Python's and NumPy's slicing semantics work for you. No need to calculate boundaries.